# How to transparently show non-additive measures in Analysis Services as if they were additive

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

In my cube there are certain measures which are non-additive, however I can compute a value for every drill down level. Unfortunately the computation is too complex for it to be done in in Analysis Services.
If I precompute the drill down levels I'm interested in, I have to put those values into a separate fact-table / measure group for each drill down level, or don't I? Is it possible to do this in a way that is transparent to the end user? So it should look like there is only one fact table and SSAS automatically selects the value from the correct fact table based on the drill-down level?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a Microsoft forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/d5998b23-936b-4e7b-b593-bd164b20c022

On the Calculate tab you can define a scope statement:

> In this really trivial example, internet sales amount will be shown when reseller sales amount is chosen (at calendar quarters).

```
scope([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount], [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]);
    this=[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
end scope;
```